# C++11 vector with smart pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, smart-pointers

I read a lot of documentation about vector modern usage.

One of the common thing appearing is, "you can replace every push_back by emplace_back". Is it true ? I'm unsure, and the fact is I don't get the idea with a smart pointer.

So, is there a difference to emplace a smart pointer than pushing it into the vector ?

In other words :

```
myVector.emplace_back(std::make_shared< XXX >(x, y, z));
```

VS

```
myVector.push_back(std::make_shared< XXX >(x, y, z));
```

I read a comment about emplacing a smart pointer and a possible exception (low memory) raised just before the insertion leading to a memory leak. Is it true ? [Memory leaking](https://releases.llvm.org/5.0.0/tools/clang/tools/extra/docs/clang-tidy/checks/modernize-use-emplace.html#cmdoption-arg-SmartPointers)

And finally, I was hoping to write something like this :

```
myVector.emplace_back(x, y, z);
```

But I'm pretty sure, I can forget it. So that's why I'm thinking about the real benefits of emplace with smart pointers.

Comment: why do you want to store pointers in a vector in the first place?

Comment: @Raildex There are _many_ valid use cases for that.

Comment: Because I want to share items from the vector with some part of the application. But keeping a place from where accessing all of them.

Comment: @SébastienBémelmans It would be helpful if you could quote the comment that you read.

Comment: Are you using polymorphism? If not, you may probably just store the objects in the vector instead of storing pointers.

Comment: @Thomas Ok I'll try to get this comment back

Comment: @TedLyngmo No, but I can't copy this object (this will lead to incoherences) and I need a reference/pointer to it.

Comment: @SébastienBémelmans do those references / pointers need to extend the lifetime of the elements?

Comment: @Caleth No the vector is definitively the holder of these items.

Comment: @SébastienBémelmans "_I can't copy this object (this will lead to incoherences)_" - You don't need copies if the vector is the only place where you store the objects.

Comment: Please make sure to always add the primary language tag to questions. Additionally adding the language revision tag is fine if that's relevant to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no difference between the `emplace_back` and `push_back` at the start of your question, they both supply a prvalue `std::shared_ptr<XXX>` that will be passed to the move constructor of the vector element.

You can't `myVector.emplace_back(x, y, z);` if `myVector` holds `std::shared_ptr<XXX>` because there's no constructor of `std::shared_ptr<XXX>` that takes those arguments. You could do that if it were a `std::vector<XXX>`, and that would construct one `XXX` in-place.

Much of this is moot however, because copy elision means that an implementation is allowed to construct the shared pointer in place.